# get Date with query result in mongodb node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the query -

```
 var chat = db.collection('chat');
    chat.find({"chat_id":req.params.id}).toArray(function(err,data){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

result --

```
[{ _id: 55cb78a0ebfead4f78d6135b,
    username: 'tester',
 } ]
```

what i modify in query that i ge the result in this format --

```
[{ _id: 55cb78a0ebfead4f78d6135b,
    username: 'tester',
    created_date: ISODate("2011-09-07T08:37:37Z")
 } ]
```

Please tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `created_date` field in the collection?

Comment: no i don't have created_date in collection but we get created date by object id from this function getTimestamp(); and this would not included with result

Comment: I cannot understand, if you haven't that data how could you retrieve it?

Comment: Show us your collection model please

Comment: [{ _id: 55cb78a0ebfead4f78d6135b,   username: 'tester' } ]  we get created date by this function getTimestamp() i want query which including this date in result

Comment: That's a row and as you can see there isn't created_date so you can't display it because it doesn't exist. But I asked for the model, how the collection is structured not for a row.

Comment: @Michelem THis is the node native driver. Here is the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/ObjectID.html#getTimestamp). This is not mongoose.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that thanks for point me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function of JavaScript. This can tranform your array results.

```
var chat = db.collection('chat');
chat.find({"chat_id":req.params.id}).toArray(function(err,data){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        data = data.map(function(item) {
            item.created_date = item._id.getTimestamp();
            return item;
         });
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Note that the `Date` here is only accurate to the "second" as the "timestamp" in an `ObjectId` is only granular to that value.

If in fact your data is being stored as a string and not an ObjectID then cast it first:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb"),
    ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;



var chat = db.collection('chat');
chat.find({"chat_id":req.params.id}).toArray(function(err,data){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        data = data.map(function(item) {
            item.created_date = new ObjectID(item._id).getTimestamp();
            return item;
         });
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Vipul Not wit the node native Mongodb driver it does not. Which driver are you in fact using? Or is your `ObjectId` actually a string?

Comment: i am using mongodb driver no its object id

Comment: @Vipul So am I, It would seem your `_id` fields are actually strings.

Comment: @Vipul You really should fix that. Correct casting is shown above.